# Presenter creating Views in c# MVP

Tags: c#, design-patterns, winforms, mvp

I have a c# WinForms application in which I have tried to implement the Model View Presenter pattern with Passive View. I create new Views in the Presenter of my 'home screen'. I was wondering if this is bad practice, and if it is, what an alternative might be to resolve this. Also, general improvements are more than welcome.

I have asked a question before about my MVP implementation [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/146036/passive-view-implementation-in-c-mvp) (you can check it out if you want more of an idea about how I have implemented the pattern in other parts of my application.

You can find my code below.

**View**

```
public partial class HomeScreenView : Form, IHomeScreenView
{
    private HomeScreenPresenter _presenter;

    // Public members.
    public List<string> ExistingAssessments
    {
        get
        {
            var assessments = new List<string>();
            for(int i = 0; i < recentAssessments.Lines.Count(); i++)
            {
                assessments.Add(recentAssessments.Lines[i]);
            }
            return assessments;
        }
        set
        {
            recentAssessments.Text = "";
            foreach (var assessment in value)
            {
                recentAssessments.Text =  assessment + Environment.NewLine + recentAssessments.Text;
            }
        }
    }

    // Public events.
    public event EventHandler InitializingAssessments;
    public event EventHandler CreatingNewAssessment;
    public event EventHandler AddingNewStandard;
    public event EventHandler OpeningAssessment;
    public event EventHandler GeneratingReport;

    // Initialize homescreen. Create an instance of the presenter with a reference the view itsself.
    public HomeScreenView(IAssessmentsModel model)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _presenter = new HomeScreenPresenter(this, model);
    }

    // Fires the initializing assessments event.
    private void HomeScreenView_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializingAssessments?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Fires the creating new assessment event.
    private void newAssessmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreatingNewAssessment?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Fires the adding new standard event.
    private void addStandardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddingNewStandard?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Fires the opening assessment event.
    private void openAssessmentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpeningAssessment?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Fires the generating report event.
    private void generateReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GeneratingReport?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    // Displays a message.
    public void Message(string message)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class HomeScreenPresenter
{
    // Private view and model.
    private readonly IHomeScreenView _view;
    private IAssessmentsModel _model;
    private DetailScreenView detailScreenView;
    private StandardScreenView standardScreenView;
    private OpenAssessmentScreenView openAssessmentScreenView;
    private ReOpenAssessmentScreenView reOpenAssessmentScreenView;

    // Initialize the homescreen presenter with an IHomeScreenView and a new assessments model. Subsribe to necessary events.
    public HomeScreenPresenter(IHomeScreenView view, IAssessmentsModel model)
    {
        _view = view;
        _model = model;
        _view.InitializingAssessments += InitializeAssessments;
        _view.CreatingNewAssessment += CreateNewAssessment;
        _view.AddingNewStandard += AddNewStandard;
        _view.OpeningAssessment += OpenAssessment;
        _view.GeneratingReport += GenerateReport;
    }

    // Fills the list of the view with all existing assessments.
    public void InitializeAssessments(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var assessments = _model.GetDataList("Assessments", "assessment_name");

            if (assessments.Any())
            {
                HashSet<string> items = new HashSet<string>(assessments);
                assessments = items.ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < assessments.Count; i++)
                {
                    assessments[i] = (assessments[i] + ": " + _model.CheckStatus(assessments[i]));
                }

                _view.ExistingAssessments = assessments;
            }
            else _view.ExistingAssessments = new List<string>();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _view.Message("Error - Initializing assessments has failed.\n"
                + "Error message - " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    // Creates a detail screen view.
    public void CreateNewAssessment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (detailScreenView == null || detailScreenView.IsDisposed)
        {
            detailScreenView = new DetailScreenView(_model);
        }
    }

    // Creates a standard screen view.
    public void AddNewStandard(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(standardScreenView == null || standardScreenView.IsDisposed)
        {
            standardScreenView = new StandardScreenView(new StandardsModel(new DatabaseController()));
        }
    }

    // Creates an open assessment screen view.
    public void OpenAssessment(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(openAssessmentScreenView == null || openAssessmentScreenView.IsDisposed)
        {
            openAssessmentScreenView = new OpenAssessmentScreenView(_model);
        }
    }

    // Creates a re open assessment screen view.
    public void GenerateReport(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(reOpenAssessmentScreenView == null || reOpenAssessmentScreenView.IsDisposed)
        {
            reOpenAssessmentScreenView = new ReOpenAssessmentScreenView(_model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of doing this? `HashSet<string> items = new HashSet<string>(assessments);`
                `assessments = items.ToList();`

Comment: I create a HashSet to remove the duplicates, and then convert it back to a List so that I can use it as a DataSource for a Control on my form.

Comment: @MartheVeldhuis in that case, you may want to go with a more declarative LINQ expression: `assessments = assessments.Distinct().ToList();`  IIRC, it does roughly the same thing under the covers, but it's a lot more obvious what the intent is.

Comment: yea I got that from the other's answers as well. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

imo, you can simplify this bit

> ```
> var assessments = _model.GetDataList("Assessments", "assessment_name");
>
> if (assessments.Any())
> {
>   HashSet<string> items = new HashSet<string>(assessments);
>   assessments = items.ToList();
>
>   for (int i = 0; i < assessments.Count; i++)
>   {
>       assessments[i] = (assessments[i] + ": " + _model.CheckStatus(assessments[i]));
>   }
>
>   _view.ExistingAssessments = assessments;
> }
> ```

to this

```
var assessments = _model.GetDataList("Assessments", "assessment_name").Distinct();
if (assessments.Any())
{
    //assessments.ForEach(a => a += $":{_model.CheckStatus(a)}"); -> wont update values
    assessments = assessments.Select(a => a += $":{_model.CheckStatus(a)}").ToList();
    _view.ExistingAssessments = assessments;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use your solution. But I am still very new to LINQ and I have a problem because the status is not added to the assessment string. I have tried debugging and I can see that the correct status is collected, but it is not added somehow. Do you know why?

Comment: @MartheVeldhuis ahh you are absolutely right, foreach will not update the original list! I have edited my answer (notice you don't need .ToList() in the first line anymore, since we will convert it to list later)

Answer (score 1):

## Separation of concerns

> ```
> public List<string> ExistingAssessments
> {
>   get
>   {
>       var assessments = new List<string>();
>       for (int i = 0; i < recentAssessments.Lines.Count(); i++)
>       {
>           assessments.Add(recentAssessments.Lines[i]);
>       }
>       return assessments;
>   }
>   set
>   {
>       recentAssessments.Text = "";
>       foreach (var assessment in value)
>       {
>           recentAssessments.Text = assessment + Environment.NewLine + recentAssessments.Text;
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

This is an *interesing* property that desperately needs improvement.

It stores the data lines as as string that is apparently being splitted internally and you get back the lines via the `Lines` property. A lot of work to just store a few lines of text.

You should drop the string concatenation here which is with the `+` operator - that is slow by the way - and store the lines *raw* in a list. It's the job of the `Text` or some other property/method to build a full/formatted-string.

This property should ideally do only this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ExistingAssessments
{
    get
    {
        return recentAssessments.Lines.ToList();            
    }
    set
    {
        recentAssessments.Lines = value.ToList();
    }
}
```

You can `ToList` the return value and the new value so that you cannot by accident modify it from outside.

Everything else is beyond its responsibility scope.

---

I'm also not sure about its name. You are not filtering there so the prefix `Existing` is misleading. One could there are other assesments and the private filed is even called *recent* assesments. Try to be consistent. Don't change the meaning without a good reason. Why don't simply name it `Assessments` or like the field `RecentAssesments`?

---

## Other suggestions

> ```
> var assessments = new List<string>();
> for (int i = 0; i < recentAssessments.Lines.Count(); i++)
> {
>   assessments.Add(recentAssessments.Lines[i]);
> }
> return assessments;
> ```

This is much less code when done with LINQ:

```
return recentAssessments.Lines.ToList();
```

---

> ```
> if (assessments.Any())
> {
>   HashSet<string> items = new HashSet<string>(assessments);
>   assessments = items.ToList();
>
>   for (int i = 0; i < assessments.Count; i++)
>   {
>       assessments[i] = (assessments[i] + ": " + _model.CheckStatus(assessments[i]));
>   }
>
>   _view.ExistingAssessments = assessments;
> }
> else _view.ExistingAssessments = new List<string>();
> ```

There's no need for the `HashSet`, for the `Any` and the `else` part. Just create the new list right away and use `Distinct`. If there are no `assessments` it will remain simply empty. With C# 6 it's really short:

```
var assessments = 
    _model.GetDataList("Assessments", "assessment_name")
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => $"{x}: {_model.CheckStatus(x)}")
    .ToList();

_view.ExistingAssessments = assessments;
```

Comment: HI, thanks for your feedback. You gave the example to set my ExistingAssessments property by assigning a list to my recentAssessments control. However, this gives me a syntax error because recentAssessments.Lines is an array and you are trying to assign a list to it. Thought i would mention it.

Comment: @MartheVeldhuis This is just an example. I cannot know which type it really has because it isn't included in your question (or I've overseen it). I'm sure you know what I mean and I see you can fix it ;-)

Comment: Not trying to blame you, just for the clarity of your example ;p. The .Lines property is a string array, which basically means removing the .ToList() part in the setter.

Answer (score 0):

It look OK to me except that

```
private HomeScreenPresenter _presenter;
```

on the view (form) maybe should be an interface which HomeScreenPresenter implements.

Further: Instead of the presenter reacts on events on the view the view should call "passive" methods on the presenter - but it's a matter of taste maybe.

---

You are firing the InitializingAssessments event on the form each time it is activated. Shouldn't that be in the load-event?

Comment: I think indeed those first parts are a matter of taste. It is my intention to fire the event every time it is activated, because actions from my other forms often update the assessments and their names.